# Segregate Parent and Child in Bundles

Tags: apex, cpq

I want to differentiate between products based on their usage as child products or the parent product in the bundles.
For this I have added 2 checkboxes on the Product2 object called **isBundleParent** & **isBundleChild**. Now whenever a Product option is added under a product(parent). I want the **isBundleParent** checkbox to turn true for the respective parent product record. And the **isBundleChild** for the add product option to turn true in the respective product record.
How Can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example trigger that does this:

```
trigger UpdateBundleFields on PricebookEntry (after insert, after update) {
Set<Id> productIdsToUpdate = new Set<Id>();

for (PricebookEntry pbe : Trigger.new) {
    if (pbe.Product2.isBundle()) {
        // This is a bundle product, update isBundleParent field
        pbe.Product2.isBundleParent__c = true;
        productIdsToUpdate.add(pbe.Product2.Id);
    } else if (pbe.Product2.Parent_Product__c != null) {
        // This is a child product, update isBundleChild field
        Product2 parentProduct = [SELECT Id, isBundleParent__c FROM Product2 WHERE Id = :pbe.Product2.Parent_Product__c];
        parentProduct.isBundleChild__c = true;
        productIdsToUpdate.add(parentProduct.Id);
    }
}

update new List<Product2>([SELECT Id, isBundleParent__c, isBundleChild__c FROM Product2 WHERE Id IN :productIdsToUpdate]);
```

}

in this example, we first loop through the PricebookEntry records in the trigger and check whether the associated Product2 is a bundle parent or child. If it's a bundle parent, we update the isBundleParent__c field to true. If it's a child product, we look up the parent Product2 record using the Parent_Product__c field, update the isBundleChild__c field on the parent record to true, and add the parent product to a set of product IDs to update later.

Finally, we update all the Product2 records that were modified in the trigger. This updates the isBundleParent__c and isBundleChild__c fields on those records.

Note that this code assumes that you have a custom field on the Product2 object called Parent_Product__c that stores the ID of the parent product for bundle child products. You will need to modify the code to use the actual field name you have used in your org.

Comment: I want to update all products instead of the new product created.